# ActivityResultLauncher with multiple permissions

Tags: java, android

I recently started developing android and I had a question. Since startActivityForResult is depricated I try to use ActivityResultLauncher, but I don't understand how I can pass RequestCode there.
Below you can see what I mean, earlier in startActivityForResult () I passed intent and request code, but I don’t understand how to do this correctly in activityResultLauncher.
Maybe someone can help me ?
Thanks in advance.

```
private void pickStorage()
    {

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        gallery.setType("image/*");
        gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


        activityResultLauncher.launch(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);

    }

    private void pickStorageForMap()
    {


        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");

        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_MAP_GPX);
    }


    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if(result.getResultCode() == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        if(result.getData() != null)
                        {
                            int imageCount = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
                                Uri image = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                mArrayListImages.add(image);
                            }


                            numberOfImages = mArrayListImages.size();
                            for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListImages.size(); i++) {
                                Slider slider = new Slider(mArrayListImages.get(i));
                                Slider model = new Slider();

                                model.setUrl(slider.getUrl());
                                mSliderArrayList.add(model);

                                mSliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(mContext, mSliderArrayList);


                                mSliderView.setSliderAdapter(mSliderAdapter);
                                mSliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);


                            }
                        }
                    }else if(result.getResultCode() == PICK_MAP_GPX && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        if(result.getData() != null) {

                            String fileExtension = "", extension = "gpx";
                            long bytes, kb, mb, gb;
                            String size, name;

                            Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

                            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                            int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);

                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                            bytes = Math.round(cursor.getDouble(sizeIndex));
                            kb = bytes/1024;
                            mb = kb/1024;
                            gb = mb/1024;

                            if(gb > 0)
                                size = gb + " GB";
                            else if(mb > 0)
                                size = mb + " MB";
                            else
                                size = kb + " KB";

                            //String size = Long.toString(cursor.getLong(sizeIndex));

                            int index = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                            if(index > 0)
                                fileExtension = name.substring(index+1);

                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Extension: " + extension, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





                            if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(fileExtension)) {
                                mapUri = result.getData().getData();
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Type " + extension, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                showFile(name, size);
                            }else
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Choose gpx file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "There is no file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You do not need to pass a request code -- that aspect is handled for you. See [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v2.1/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/MainActivity.java#L63-75) and [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v2.1/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/MainActivity.java#L132) for an example of using `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission` in Java.

Comment: With activity result contract API request code becomes an internal implementation detail. Instead of declaring big requestcode switch in `onActivityResult` you register separate contract for each possible request and handle results in their callbacks.

Comment: @Pawel You mean I have to create two separate ActivityResultLauncher () for the map and for the image?

Comment: Yes. Also note that you can use other [ActivityResultContracts](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts) that parse resulting intent for you instead of relying on `StartActivityForResult()` contract which returns raw intent.

Answer (score 1):

With activity result contract API request code becomes an internal implementation detail. Instead of declaring big requestcode switch in onActivityResult you register separate contract for each possible request and handle results in their callbacks.